# How to remove items when a specific date is selected in the MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, mysql

When I select a specific date like in the code  I have in MonthCalendar I delete some items in a listbox, but after that when I select Another date in the MonthCalendar I want the items back in the listbox, how to do this? Iam not getting the items back after the selection of a specific date.

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged_1(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MyConn3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection3);
        string mday= monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string test = ("select day, time, name from system where day='"+mday+"'");
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(test, MyConn3);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        try
        {
            MyConn3.Open();
            MyReader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (MyReader2.Read())
            {
                 eDay = MyReader2.GetString("day");                    
                 eTime = MyReader2.GetString("time");
                string namn = MyReader2.GetString("name");

                if (eDay.Contains(mday))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("time " + eTime);
                    Console.WriteLine(eDay);
                    Console.WriteLine(eTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("test: " + mday);

                    listBox1.Items.Remove(eTime);
                }
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        MyConn3.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep dataSource of listBox1 before "monthCalendar1_DateChanged_1" method starts to work.

In the beginning of method you have to set the dataSource to listBox1 and then remove items from listBox. So the code will be stg like this:

```
private List<string> myGlobalDataSource= new List<string>{"item1","item2"};

private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged_1(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = myGlobalDataSource;
        MyConn3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection3);

....
```

Comment: in the begining I have these items added in the list: string[] meep = { "08:00-12:00", "12:00-16:00", "16:00-20:00" };  and I want to remove when a I select a date wich mathes in the database.